# How to decide if a Surface Pro 3 is a tablet or desktop computer?

Tags: mobile, browser, desktop, user-agent, windows-10

I am doing research on how a web application in ASP.NET should detect a computer like Surface Pro 3 running Windows 10 and route it to the simple mobile web application (responsive and adapts to mobile and tablets) or to the more complex and rich desktop web application.

I can see many suggestions reading the user agent from the browser. But this gives me limited options to choose from.

The user agent of the computer is:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240

The screen resolution is:
12.0 inches (30 cm) 2160x1440 (216 ppi)

So here we have multiple issues.

- The Surface Pro 3 form factor can act both as a tablet and desktop. It has a high resolution but also high DPI since the screen is quite small. So, when people say they choose mobile because of resolution I believe we can't do that anymore since we have full HD and above also on mobiles these days. We should know the physical size of the screen. Is it possible to gather that information?
- The user agent here does not say anything about touch capabilities, so that clearly varies from browser to browser. And also, can we call a touch enabled device a tablet? I don't think so, because we can have 60 inch touch devices.

So how do we present to the user a complex application or simple application? can we automate a default choice for this that makes sense?

Currently, I think the best solution is to give the user a choice the first time when the user agent does not say mobile. That means it can be a tablet or desktop.

Any clever solutions to this?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't have separate versions of your app for desktop and mobile.

Comment: So THAT's the reason you say? So a technical issue that makes me unable to fully detect what kind of device is visiting the site, and not functional and UX requirements is the decider?

Comment: No.  The whole notion of a "kind of device" is rapidly losing meaning in today's world of hybrid devices.  What will you do for an HP TouchSmart?

Comment: That is up to the enterprise I work for. They know the machines they have and they want to define the machine types internally. This is also an enterprise internal application we are talking about. Mobile exposing 10-20 most important func. Desktop version 100+ functions that simply does not make sense on mobile. Also makes no sense to write that many media queries. So, back to what I am really asking about. Is there a technical solution to detect device types other than user agent or is that all we have?